# How to deploy changes made to my django project, which is hosted on pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I am new to git and Pythonanywhere. So, I have a live Django website which is hosted with the help of Pythonanywhere. I have made some improvements to it. I have committed and pushed that changes to my Github repository. But, now I don't know that how to further push that changes to my Pythonanywhere website. I am so confused. Please help!!! Forgive me, I am new to it.

Comment: Login into their shell and clone the repo there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the repo on PythonAnywhere in a bash console, run `git pull` (You may need to run `./mange.py migrate` if you made changes to your models) and then reload the app on "Web" configuration page on PythonAnywhere. .